# Debian buster r-base won't upgrade to 3.6.3

Tags: debian, apt

I have 2 computers (a PC and a server) with debian buster as OS. I need to backport the R language version from 3.5.2 to 3.6.3 on both. I follow this guide : https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/debian/.
And so, on both configuration of apt, the ***same*** apt source file is set for R CRAN :
`deb https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CRAN/bin/linux/debian buster-cran35/`
But the r-base package version is different on the 2 computers. On the server, there is the desired 3.6.3 version and on the PC this is the legacy 3.5.2 version still installed.

When I use apt dist-upgrade on the server, R version upgrade but not on the PC.

I try to unsintall all R packages on the PC and force to install R with the desired version but it does'nt work. I try to use aptitude to see missing dependencies but nothing regarding R (just one for firefox).

How can I do to upgrade the backport version of R on the PC, did I miss something ?

arnome.

Answer (score 0):

The steps should be:

1. Add

   ```
   deb https://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CRAN/bin/linux/debian buster-cran35/
   ```

   to `/etc/apt/sources.list` or to a new file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/r-base.list`
2. Import the key with

   ```
   sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key 'E19F5F87128899B192B1A2C2AD5F960A256A04AF'
   ```
3. Update the package index

   ```
   sudo apt update
   ```
4. Install the package if you uninstalled `r-base`

   ```
   sudo apt install r-base
   ```

   **or** upgrade the package if it is already installed (3.5.2-1)

   ```
   sudo apt upgrade
   ```

Comment: Hi, this is exactly what I do (I use a different file than sources.list) but R is stucked in 3.5.2. More generaly, I have no upgrade anymore.

Comment: Apparently, I have libc6 dependencies problems : ```r-base-core : depends libc6 (>=2.29) but 2.28-10 should be installed``` I have the 2 versions as pkg candidate (apt show -a) but 2.29 broke locales...

Comment: Hmm. Buster's [r-base-core (3.5.2-1)](https://packages.debian.org/buster/r-base-core) should depened on libc6 >= 2.27 and
[libc6 (2.28-10)](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libc6) is the default version. 
My guess is that you have already installed some `r-base` packages from a different repository (maybe [bullseye](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/r-base-core)?) which are not compatibe. Try to uninstall these packages first, maybe with `apt remove -f` to get to a clean state before you proceed.
Use `apt policy <pkgname>` to check where these packages came from.

Comment: And of course remove all non-needed repositories from your sources and don't forget to run `sudo apt update` before you try to install 3.6.3.

Comment: Thank's Freddy. The problem was that some bioconductor debian packages was on my install list. I have to pin CRAN packages to stuck R in backport version and it works. After that, I install all needed packages throw R interface.